# method parse of the LogRecord

Tags: java, regex, scala, date

The logs are an ASCII file with one line per request, with the following columns:

1. Host making the request.
2. Not used
3. A hostname when possible, otherwise the Internet address if the name could not be looked up.
4. Timestamp in the format "DAY MON DD HH:MM:SS YYYY", where DAY is the day of the week, MON is the name of the month, DD is the day of the month, HH:MM:SS is the time of day using a 24-hour clock, and YYYY is the year. The timezone is -0400.
5. Request given in quotes.
6. HTTP reply code.
7. Bytes in the reply.

So, strings like this should be parsed:

> 202.32.92.47 - - [01/Jun/1995:00:00:59 -0600] "GET "run/~scottp/publish.html" 200 271
>
> ix-or7-27.ix.netcom.com - John Dou [01/Jun/1995:00:02:51 -0600] "GET /~ladd/ostriches.html" 200 205908

And those should be ignored:

> maz3.maz.net - - [11/Oa67220.dial.tip.net - - [12/Oct/1995:01:39:12 -0600] "POST /cgi-bin/phone.pl HTTP/1.0" 200 309
>
> 129.186.123.55 - - [12/Oct/1995ag5881.usask.ca - - [12/Oct/1995:16:07:36 -0600] "GET /images/letter_32.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 149

Have tried a lot of regexps as `^([^\s]*).-.([^\s]*)?.\[([^\]]*)]."([^\"]*)".([^\s]\d*).([^\s]\d*)?$`

But either it didn't ignore mistaken logs from above, or it simply caused errors.

Comment: you can try https://regexr.com/ and paste your following examples into the text area with variations of your regex to see how and where it's failing

Comment: Your question is hard to follow and needs to be improved, especially with regard to what characteristic determines which should be selected and which should not.  Write those as JUnit test first.